# sorting a vector of coordinate structs

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have this coordinate type:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct coords {
        T1 x;
        T2 y;
};

std::vector<coords<int, int>> pixels;
```

and I want to sort each `x[]` and `y[]` using `std::sort` or any other function that can handle it. As a workaround I thought of copying `x` and `y` into separate vectors, and then use `std::sort` on them independently it and finally copy the result back into `pixels`.

I came up with:

```
for (auto ita : pixels) {
    for (auto itb : pixels) {
        if (ita.x > itb.x) std::swap(ita.x, itb.x);
        if (ita.y > itb.y) std::swap(ita.y, itb.y);
    }
}
```

Just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: I came up with: `for (auto ita : pixels) {for (auto itb : pixels) { if (ita.x > itb.x)std::swap(ita.x, itb.x); if (ita.y > itb.y) std::swap(ita.y, itb.y);}}}`

Comment: If you want to provide additional code, please [edit] your question, do not provide it in comments...

Comment: What should the result be? First sorted by `x` and then by `y`? Do you expect two results: one sorted by `x`, one by `y`? Please clarify.

Comment: Give an example of an input and the expected sorted result.

Comment: What happens if you have points p1 =  (3, 4) and p2 = (4, 3). Is p1 < p2 because the x coordinate 3 is less than 4? Or is p2 < p1 because the y coordinate 3 is less than 4? You don't seem to have clear definition of what the order is.

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do:

```
ranges::sort(pixels | ranges::view::transform(&coords<int, int>::x));
ranges::sort(pixels | ranges::view::transform(&coords<int, int>::y));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ae4eca266384629)